# Reading array from comma separated text file

Tags: java, arrays

Want to print out a matrix in a comma separated text file, but this code will print out  matrix with all zeroes which is not the matrix in the text file .

```
public int[][] readFromFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Aidan\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\matrix\\src\\matrix\\newfile"));
    int[][] a = new int[9][9];
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String word = in.next();
        if (word.equals(",")) {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println(word);
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        //System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(word));
        int s = Integer.parseInt(word);
        a[x++][y++] = s;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using something like the apache commons csv library for something like this. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @user1875195 is completely right.  I've seen too much hand-built code that works for one csv file and fails for the next.  Very few applications obey the csv standard rigorously so you need a parser that can handle variation.  Most hand-built parsers fail to handle both (one,two,three) and ("one, seven", two, three), both of which are valid csv.

Comment: To help with your case we need to see the csv file you're importing and the output (ir particular, the output of the println(word))

Comment: Can you please post the input file, and tell what are you trying to achieve. Your approach works only if the commas are surrounded by spaces. It is hard to figure out what is your goal with the array, and the way how you write the array looks strange. In fact you're not writing each element, just diagonally from 0,0, 1,1, 2,2, 3,3, 4,4, 5,5 ?

Comment: Why not load the whole file, then use String.split() to separate them?

Comment: the file looks like something like this. 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ....

Comment: ive also tried something like this.

Comment: public String[] readFromFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Aidan\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\matrix\\src\\matrix\\newfile");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        fis.read(data);
        fis.close();

        String str = new String(data, "UTF-8");
        String[] a = str.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
        return a;
    }

Comment: sorry new to this form, how do i submit code after intial question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple lines in your csv file:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1
3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2
...
```

You should be able to do something like the following:

```
int[][] a = new int[9][9];
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("C:\..."));
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    String[] line = in.nextLine().split(",");
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        a[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line[j]);
    }
}
```

This is the bare minimum, and includes no error checking, if a line in your csv has less than 9 comma separated numbers, the program will crash.